# Помогите разобраться в ООП php при работе с Битриксом?

Tags: php, ооп, битрикс

Работаю по [этому](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uJh2s5Ao0s) уроку.
Когда дошел до проверки, могу ли я запустить мастер, получаю ошибку типа `Using $this when not in object context (0)`.
Код класа со строкой ошибки

```
class ParseRssWizardTools{
    //return select
public function ShowSelectField($name, $arValues=array(), $arAttributes){
    $wizard = $this->GetWizard();
    }
}
```

и вызов

```
$this->content .= ParseRssWizardTools::ShowSelectField('IBLOCK_ID', 
 $arIBlocks) . "</th></tr>";
```

ругается на `$wizard = $this->GetWizard();`

Comment: а где, например, ваша функция GetWizard() ??

Comment: @Arsen https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/general/wizards/api/cwizardstep/getwizard.php

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к нестатическому методу как к статическому,  При этом в статическом методе нельзя использовать $this.... т.к. нет объекта....
Потому вам надо сначала создать объект ParseRssWizardTools , а потом уж обращаться к методу
  $obj = new ParseRssWizardTools();
  $obj->ShowSelectField(....)  или переделать на статик.

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр пробовал тоже этот способ, который вы указываете, тогда ошибка другая совсем, но тоже есть

`Call to undefined method ParseRssWizardTools::GetWizard()`

Comment: Ну так, а он у вас определен? В листинге его нет.....

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр http://joxi.ru/gmvljzOHOL9dAa
и вызов http://joxi.ru/Vm64klztoDwkAZ, просто иду по уроку, и столкнулся с проблемой этой... А как его опредилить?

Comment: Вы дали ссылку выше... Посмотрите на отличя вашего кода и кода в документации... там extends CWizardStep  не случайно... Вы здесь полный код своего класса привели?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56652/discussion-between-oleksandr-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Сам класс очевидно должен быть наследником `CwizardStep`

```
class ParseRssWizardTools extends CWizardStep{
   //return select
   public function ShowSelectField($name, $arValues=array(), $arAttributes){
      $wizard = $this->GetWizard();
   }
}
```

А вызов должен быть явно динамическим

```
$wizaredStep = new ParseRssWizardTools();
$wizardStep->ShowSelectField('IBLOCK_ID', $arIBlocks);
```

Таким образом ошибки не будет. Но скорее всего вы поступаете немного неправильно. Т.к. шаги мастера в битриксе обычно описываются в фале `.description.php` в папке мастера. При прямом вызове, который вы написали шаг мастера не знает о самом мастере. `$wizard` будет равен `null`.

Comment: все шаги стандартных мастеров описаны почему-то в "bitrix" папке.